# How to use LaTeX with Blender?

Tags: latex

I'm using a custom add on for the 3d program Blender to write latex.

The add on needs to know where the latex installation is:

[image]

I know I have latex Installed (texlive) but whatever path I have tried did not work.

I would love your suggestion on this.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question by saying what paths you have tried?  (And how you arrived at them.)

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/bin/latex`?

Comment: I tried `/usr/bin/latex`, `/usr/share/man/man1/latex.1.gz`, `/usr/local/texlive` without luck.

Comment: Did you install both blender and latex from apt?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Good question - I only installed latex from apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to replace the snap version of blender with its apt version.

```
sudo snap remove blender
sudo apt install blender
```

If you need the latest version of blender, use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/blender). Note that it only supports LTS versions of Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/blender
sudo apt update
sudo apt install blender
```

(If you want to use the latest LTS version of Blender (3.3.3 as of now), use `sudo apt install blender-lts` after adding the PPA).